# Relative URL for stylesheet not working with CodeIgniter

Tags: css, codeigniter

Config is WAMP + CodeIgniter.

I am trying to use jQuery stylesheet in my view. But relative folder doesn't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="views/style/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

My dir structure is

```
htdocs
  application
    views\style\themes\smoothness
  system
```

Link for stylesheet created in html source code is

```
localhost/instantCheckController/views/style/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
```

Why controller name is getting prefixed to the stylesheet url?

However, replacing relative path with absolute web path to jquery-ui.css works and stylesheet gets applied.

I want to use relative path to local stylesheet files and not web path. What's wrong with my relative path?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
echo link_tag('views/style/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
```